# Get keys by list of values

Tags: python

I have a dictionary and a list of values such as:

```py
dictionary = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}

liste = [2, 3]
```

I would like:

```py
result = ['b', 'c']
```

If I have a **very large** dictionary, what is the most optimal way to do this?

The keys have unique values.

Comment: How often do you want to perform this kind of lookup on the same dict, and do keys have unique (and hashable) values? Typically you "reverse" the dict once and perform the value-to-key lookups on the reversed dict.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea here is to create a reverse_dict for an efficient lookup, otherwise the complexity can be O(mn), m-number of keys, n-length of liste. A value can be duplicate, so keeping a list for the keys is also important.

```
result = []
reverse_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    reverse_dict[value].append(key) 
for v in liste:
    result.extend(reverse_dict[v])
```

Comment: Edited to remove the unnecessary list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

```
dictionary = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}

liste = [2, 3]

result = []
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    if value in liste:
        result.append(key)
```

As a list comprehension:

`result = [key for key, value in dictionary.items() if value in liste]`

Answer (score 0):

Lookup by value is exactly what dictionaries are **not** meant for.

Since you said the dictionary is very large, the most efficient solution relies on how many times you're operating on it.

If it's going to be a frequent task, you may need to create a reverse dictionary. This can be done comprehensively:

```
rev_dict = {v: k for k, v in dictionary.items()}
```

Then you can lookup the dictionary the way it's designed for.

On the contrary, an isolated case does not justify creating a copy of a very large dictionary, which can be memory and time consuming. So I came up with this awful messy un-Pythonic construct, which exploits the ordered feature of Python 3.7+ dictionaries:

```
list(dictionary.keys())[list(dictionary.values()).index(your_value)]
```

Mind you, use this only if you're desperate.

Obviously, the best solution is the one everybody knows but no-one wants: hardcode a reverse dictionary before running the script.

This can also bring some issues to your attention that the above solutions are unable to avoid at runtime (not without being explicitly handled), e.g. reversing your dict may result in having duplicate keys, which is not illegal, but will result in a sadly shortened dictionary.